# Como utilizar Optional.ofNullable() neste exemplo?

Tags: java, java-8

Nesse exemplo, como posso utilizar esse recurso para evitar `NullPointerException` nos `get`?

```
public Pessoa parse()
{
     Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
     RespostaPessoaEncontrada pessoaEncontrada = ObjectMapperFactory.getInstance()
                   .readValue(jsonObject.toString(), RespostaPessoaEncontrada.class);

     pessoa.setNome(pessoaEncontrada.getDados().getCabecalho().getNome());

     pessoa.setCargo(pessoaEncontrada.getDados().getProfissao().getNome());

     pessoa.setIrmao(pessoaEncontrada.getClasse().getFamilia().getIrmao().getNome();

     return pessoa;
}
```

Comment: Utilizando recursos do java 8 (map,filter), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Considerando a seguinte implementação da classe `Dados`, que pode ter telefone nulo:

```
public class Dados {

  private String telefone;

  public Dados(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
  }

  public Optional<String> getTelefone() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(telefone);
  }
}
```

E a seguinte implementação da classe `Pessoa`, que pode ter todos os campos nulos:

```
public class Pessoa {

  private String nome;
  private Dados dados;

  public Pessoa(String nome, Dados dados) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.dados = dados;
  }

  public Optional<String> getNome() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(nome);
  }

  public Optional<Dados> getDados() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(dados);
  }
}
```

Podemos ter a garantia que nenhum dos trechos abaixo vai gerar uma `NullPointerException`.

---

Invocar toString em uma variável que pode ser nula

```
Optional<PessoaEncontrada> pessoaNull = Optional.ofNullable(null);
pessoaNull.ifPresent(p -> {
  // Executado somente se pessoa nao for null
  System.out.println(p.toString());
});

Optional<PessoaEncontrada> pessoaNonNull = Optional.of(new PessoaEncontrada(null, null));
pessoaNonNull.ifPresent(p -> {
  // Executado somente se pessoa nao for null
  System.out.println(p.toString());
});
```

---

Printar o nome de uma pessoa, todo em caixa alta, sendo que a pessoa e o nome podem ser nulos

```
Optional<PessoaEncontrada> pessoa2Null = Optional.ofNullable(null);
pessoa2Null.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getNome)
    .ifPresent(nome -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa e nome nao forem null
      System.out.println(nome.toUpperCase());
    });

Optional<PessoaEncontrada> pessoa2NonNullNomeNull = Optional.of(new PessoaEncontrada(null, null));
pessoa2NonNullNomeNull.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getNome)
    .ifPresent(nome -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa e nome nao forem null
      System.out.println(nome.toUpperCase());
    });

Optional<PessoaEncontrada> pessoa2NonNullNomeNonNull = Optional.of(new PessoaEncontrada("fulano", null));
pessoa2NonNullNomeNonNull.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getNome)
    .ifPresent(nome -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa e nome nao forem null
      System.out.println(nome.toUpperCase());
    });
```

---

Printar o telefone de uma pessoa, sendo que pessoa, dados e telefone podem ser nulos

```
Optional<PessoaEncontrada> dadosPessoaNull = Optional.ofNullable(null);
dadosPessoaNull.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getDados)
    .flatMap(Dados::getTelefone)
    .ifPresent(tel -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa, dados e telefone nao forem null
      System.out.println(tel.toUpperCase());
    });

Optional<PessoaEncontrada> dadosNull = Optional.of(new PessoaEncontrada(null, null));
dadosNull.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getDados)
    .flatMap(Dados::getTelefone)
    .ifPresent(tel -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa, dados e telefone nao forem null
      System.out.println(tel.toUpperCase());
    });

Optional<PessoaEncontrada> dadosNonNullTelNull = Optional.of(new PessoaEncontrada("hello", new Dados(null)));
dadosNonNullTelNull.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getDados)
    .flatMap(Dados::getTelefone)
    .ifPresent(tel -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa, dados e telefone nao forem null
      System.out.println(tel.toUpperCase());
    });

Optional<PessoaEncontrada> dadosNonNullTelNonNull = Optional.of(new PessoaEncontrada("hello", new Dados("1122")));
dadosNonNullTelNonNull.flatMap(PessoaEncontrada::getDados)
    .flatMap(Dados::getTelefone)
    .ifPresent(tel -> {
      // Executado somente se pessoa, dados e telefone nao forem null
      System.out.println(tel.toUpperCase());
    });
```

---

No seu caso, alterando os *getters* das classes pra retornar Optionals, você poderia alterar a seguinte linha:

```
pessoa.setNome(pessoaEncontrada.getDados().getCabecalho().getNome());
```

Para algo como:

```
pessoaEncontrada.getDados()
    .flatMap(Dados::getCabecalho)
    .flatMap(Cabecalho::getNome)
    .ifPresent(pessoa::setNome);
```