# Para que serve o Optional do Java 8? Como usar?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, java-8, option

Qual a utilidade do [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) do Java 8? Como se usa esse recurso?

As melhores respostas que achei no site foram essas...

[Qual a diferença entre os métodos orElse() e orElseGet() do java.util.Optional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438340/357)

[Como utilizar Optional.ofNullable() neste exemplo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251541/357)

...mas acho que cabe uma pergunta mais genérica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Finalidade

É bem engraçado porque o maior motivo para usã-lo é evitar exceções, justo na linguagem que inventou o abuso no seu uso :)

Quando você pode ter um resultado ou não, a forma normal do Java sempre foi dar uma exceção quando não der o resultado, então um método pode tomar duas ações, dar um resultado ou desviar o fluxo de forma brutal, [pagando um preço bem alto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101) e [complicando o fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101) em muitos casos. Na verdade "sempre" é um pouco de exagero porque há muitos casos que o método retorna `null` ou algum código de erro como em [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)). Falo tudo isso em [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Então desde a versão 8, quando a situação não é excepcional, é normal que aconteça um problema e um resultado pode não ser possível, uma das soluções seria retornar um `Optional`, aí você tem um erro ou o resultado.

Com ele você só pode pegar o resultado se ele existir e tem que testar de alguma forma (há facilitadores), não corre o risco de pegar um resultado inválido, e é obrigado verificar, ao contrário da exceção que não é obrigado (mesmo que a crença popular é que seja).

As linguagens modernas tem preferido isso do que a exceção. Mesmo as que ainda querem exceção usam praticamente como código de erro.

Não tem em Java padrão, mas há quem use `Maybe` (um Monad) ou `Result` (informa qual erro deu e não só se deu certo ou não) como outras formas de ter um resultado que pode existir ou não.

## Como usar

Eu acho que a parte de como usar seria outra pergunta, mas vamos lá, pelo menos um exemplo básico, para falar de todos ficaria muito amplo.

```
Optional<User> user = findUserById("1234");
if (user.isPresent()) System.out.println("Nome do usuário = " + user.get().getName());
```

A forma mais funcional de fazer:

```
user.ifPresent((user) -> {
    System.out.println("Nome do usuário = " + user.getName());  
})
```

Esse método deve ser algo assim (de forma muito simplificada):

```
Optional<User> findUserById(string id) {
    var user = database.user.query(id); //pode retornar null
    return Optional.ofNullable(user);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Optional2.java).

Quando o objeto não pode ser nulo e quer indicar que não haverá resultado pode usar `Optional.empty()`, desta forma o objeto terá um indicativo que não há resultado e portanto não pode usá-lo.

Antes o normal era retornar só o `null`, o que poderia ser prontamente ignorado e dar o famoso `Nullpointerexception`. Ou poderia dar um `throw` que virava uma tragédia (que programadores Java viviam dizendo que não importava, e agora andam mudando de ideia porque a linguagem pode fazer de um jeito melhor - isso chama-se *fanboyismo*).

Fica claro que o `indexOf()`, ou `parse()` e seus assemelhados de vários objetos, e boa parte dos métodos que retornam `null` deveriam ter usado esse mecanismo se ele existisse antes, né?

O uso dele se torna mais importante ainda quando o método não acessa um recurso externo, porque um banco de dados gerar uma exceção não é o fim do mundo, ainda que semanticamente não achar o usuário é algo esperado e não excepcional, por isso a exceção não é o mecanismo mais adequado. Uma validação simples ou um cálculo já é um problema enorme abusar da exceção quando é normal que ocorra uma falha (ainda pode ser útil lançar exceção quando é algo que não deveria ocorrer, como uma divisão por zero por exemplo).

## Conclusão

Esta forma é mais declarativa e menos imperativa, por isso é considerada mais funcional.

Pena que a linguagem colocou isso antes de ter tipos por valor na linguagem, então ele é uma classe, é feio e ineficiente.

Eu acho que cabem perguntas mais específicas.

Java praticamente criou a ideia de linguagem "exclusivamente" orientada a objeto, o que nunca foi verdade, e agora, para o bem, adotou um estilo funcional, em parte, e a comunidade tem abraçado isso (pelo menos boa parte dela, que pensa um pouco, que seguem boas referências). O que me entristece é que C# que pegou carona em Java, adotou o funcional antes porque "nunca" se vendeu como OO, e ainda tem gente referência na comunidade que é contra o uso desse mecanismo de resultado opcional e prefere a exceção (em alguns países há mais aceitação, eles possuem melhores referências).

Comment: Eu particularmente acho muito feio utilizar `isPresent()`, não elimina a necessidade de uma condicional para checar internamente um [!= null](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l140). Eu acho mais prático utilizar os métodos estáticos `Optional.of()` e `Optional.ofNullable` combinados com `get`, `orElse`, `orElseGet` e `orElseThrow`

Comment: É, a linguagem nunca ajudou muito, mas é um avanço.